# SpriteBatch Offset in Libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

I've recently noticed that my sprite batch renders the sprites at an offset compared to the screen. (About half the sprite's width/height). I want my SpriteBatch to work in screen coordinates so that I can use that in order to calculate the current vector pointing from the sprite to my mouse. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Never work in screen coordinates. That will make it very difficult for you to handle screens with different resolutions. Work in world space (defined by the camera's viewportWidth and viewportHeight. Use the camera to project screen coordinates into world space. Suggested reading: https://xoppa.github.io/blog/pixels/

Comment: You probably assume the sprite to be placed at the position you put it, with the sprites center, but sprites are usually positioned with the lower left edge. Maybe using the [Sprite.setCenter(float, float)](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.html#setCenter-float-float-) method instead of the `setPosition(float, float)` method fixes it?

Comment: sprite.setOriginCenter();
sprite.setOriginBasedPosition(x,y);

Comment: After a bit, those two seem to fix it.